# Hosting 2 node application in plesk

Tags: node.js, plesk

Is there any way to host 2 **NodeJS** app in a single `root` file?

I'm hosting my clients app in 1 single `root` file but they have 2 application but **Plesk** can only host one node in a single `root` in my observation.

I have 2 `PHP` application on **Plesk** hosted in a single `root`. I'm not sure why can't I host 2 `node` application in a single `root` file.

I tried to search in the internet but I only find 1 solution but in my case it is difficult to me to execute.

**Solution:**

It's called [Conditional Response](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/templates/pages/conditional_response/)

Is there any other way on how to put 2 application in **Plesk**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be help you

[Hosting multiple apps on the same server — Implement a reverse proxy with Node](https://itnext.io/hosting-multiple-apps-on-the-same-server-implement-a-reverse-proxy-with-node-a4e213497345)